# Python difficulty running functions in parallel

Tags: python, multithreading

I am currently Using python 2.6 and am attempting to run another python script multiple times with different input, and whatever attempts I do to run it in the background, it seems that the script waits for the process to complete, before moving on to the next line. I have tried using

`subprocess.Popen(Some.Func(Args))`

and

`T1 = threading.Thread(Some.Func(Args))
 T1.start()`

I would like to be able to run through multiple calls to Some class without waiting on any particular one to finish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing the arguments to your classes correctly. You want to use `multiprocessing.Process` or `threading.Thread`. Specify your `target` and `args` separately from each other. The following example demonstrates running ten processes in parallel followed by ten threads in parallel:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import multiprocessing
import threading


def main():
    for executor in multiprocessing.Process, threading.Thread:
        engines = []
        for _ in range(10):
            runner = executor(target=for_loop, args=(0, 10000000, 1))
            runner.start()
            engines.append(runner)
        for runner in engines:
            runner.join()


def for_loop(start, stop, step):
    accumulator = start
    while accumulator < stop:
        accumulator += step


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: @Erudaki That depends on what you want to accomplish. If the method of the class returns data, then you have to "install plumbing" to have that data returned in a reasonable fashion. If the method of the class makes changes to the instance's state, you will need more plumbing if you use `multiprocessing.Process` to run the method. My recommendation would be to either modify your class or subclass it and add a method to asynchronously run the method for you.